# print method for Generic Stack in java

Tags: java, generics, data-structures

I have a problem finding a solution for this peculiar problem. 
I have this class of a generic Stack.

```
    class Pilita<T> {
private int tam;
private T[] arregloPila;
private int tope; 

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public Pilita(int tam) {
       this.tam=tam;
       arregloPila=(T[])new Object[tam];
       tope=-1;
}
public void push(T valor){
       if(pilaLlena()){
              throw new StackFullException("No se puede meter el: "+"["+valor+"]"+" La pila esta llena");
       }
       arregloPila[++tope]=valor;
}
public T pop() {
       if(pilaVacia()){
              throw new StackEmptyException("La pila esta vacia");
       }
       return arregloPila[tope--]; 
}
public boolean pilaVacia(){
       return (tope == -1);
}
public boolean pilaLlena(){
       return (tope==tam-1);
}
public int contar(){
 return(tope+1);   
}
```

And I want to know how to implement a method to print the stack, because i have a method for normal stacks, but it doesn't seems to work with Generic Stack.

Any help would be Helpful.

Comment: Where is your method to print the generic stack, and what doesn't work about it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the simplest way to print a Java array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/409784/whats-the-simplest-way-to-print-a-java-array)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To print the all the stack, you only need to check if the stack is not empty

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Pilita pila = new Pilita(3);
        pila.push("1");
        pila.push("2");
        pila.push("3");
        while (!pila.pilaVacia()) {
            System.out.println("Pil pop " + pila.pop());
        }
    }
```